# how can i take many values from dictionary and put it a choicefield?

Tags: python, dictionary, choicefield

I have a list of dictionaries when I tried to put many values from the list I got this error:

```
ErrorType 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

this is my function:

```
def chooseOneServer():

     i=0
     for item in data:
         for key,value in item.items :
             if key == '1' :
                 servers = (
                        ('i',value), 

               ) 
                i +=1  
    return servers 


data =[{'1': value1.1,... },{'1':value2.1,...}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem lies in this line:

```
for key,value in item.items:
```

`dict.items()` is a method, so `item.items` will give you the actual method (you then try to iterate over this method, hence the error). Instead, you want to call that method and get the result, so you'll need parentheses:

```
for key,value in item.items():
```

Comment: it works but it shows the last item from the last dictionnary
how can get all the item needed

Comment: Instead of `servers = (('i', value),)`, do something like `servers.append(('i', value))` and add `servers = []` near `i=0`.